# In Nmap, which flags does -A include?

Tags: enums, enumeration, nmap, port-scanning

-A: Enable OS detection, version detection, script scanning, and traceroute

I was thinking that it covers -O, -sV, -sC, --traceroute, but I'm not 100% sure.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the very basic question btw. The answer seems obvious to me, but I wanted to make sure because I had seen Cyber Mentor use -A in addition to -O which confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://nmap.org/man/de/man-briefoptions.html these are the descriptions of the flags

```
-A: Enables OS detection and Version detection, Script scanning and Traceroute
```

vs.

```
-O: Enable OS detection
-sV: Probe open ports to determine service/version info
-sC: equivalent to --script=default
--traceroute: Trace hop path to each host
```

So they are the same. Was also answered [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/13908).